# Disable autosave for a programmatically taken photo?

Tags: android, delphi, camera

With my android app written with Delphi 10.3 CE, the user can take a photo by clicking a button. This works fine and gives me the ability to save the bitmap in a stream or elsewhere. It is not necessary to save the picture to a file (besides this, the OS saves two copies of the photo). So I want to disable autosaving. Is there a way, please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TTakePhotoFromCameraAction), it has a [`NeedSaveToAlbum`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TCustomTakePhotoAction.NeedSaveToAlbum) property that you can set to False.

If you are using [`IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto), it has an overload that accepts a [`TParamsPhotoQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery) as input, which has a [`NeedSaveToAlbum`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery.NeedSaveToAlbum) field.

Comment: I indeed use TakePhotoFromCameraAction1 and already its property NeedSaveToAlbum is set to FALSE but it saves (twice).

Comment: Then there is probably nothing you can do about it in FMX, you would likely have to access Android's camera APIs directly instead.

Comment: Apparently setting NeedSaveToAlbum has the reverse effect, i.e. set it to True to prevent the picture from being saved. I am yet to check this myself.

Comment: I've ran a small test and the pic gets saved to the album irregardless of the flag (Delphi 10.3 Rio CE)